# Javascript: Get value of json string

Tags: javascript, json, string

I have this JSON string:

```
var json = {
  "cdl": {
    "06A78000000YNR7EAO": {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "CDL",
        "url": "/services/data"
      },
      "CDI": "06978000000GIjCAAW",
      "LEI": "a1U78000000SUtTEAW",
      "Id": "06A78000000YNR7EAO",
      "CD": {
        "attributes": {
          "type": "CD",
          "url": "/services/data"
        },
        "Title": "photo-1517849845537-4d257902454a",
        "Id": "06978000000GIjCAAW"
      }
    },
    "06A78000000YNPGEA4": {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "CDL",
        "url": "/services/data"
      },
      "CDI": "06978000000GIhuAAG",
      "LEI": "a1U78000000SUtOEAW",
      "Id": "06A78000000YNPGEA4",
      "CD": {
        "attributes": {
          "type": "CD",
          "url": "/services/data"
        },
        "Title": "photo-1517519014922-8fc06b814a0e",
        "Id": "06978000000GIhuAAG"
      }
    }
  },
  "documents": {
    "a1U78000000SUtTEAW": {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "DR",
        "url": "/services/data"
      },
      "Id": "a1U78000000SUtTEAW",
      "Name": "test2"
    },
    "a1U78000000SUtOEAW": {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "DR",
        "url": "/services/data"
      },
      "Id": "a1U78000000SUtOEAW",
      "Name": "test"
    }
  }
}
```

I can access to the document name like this:

```
console.log(Object.values(json)[1]["a1U78000000SUtTEAW"]["Name"]);
```

how can i know how much documents are and how can i get the name without using `"a1U78000000SUtTEAW"`?

Comment: Do you want to get all the names or just the one with id "a1U78000000SUtTEAW"

Comment: all the names but without using that string.

Comment: You already know how: `Object.values`. `Object.values(json.documents).length` and `Object.values(json.documents).map(d => d.Name)`.

Comment: Your "JSON" is not correct, as you should have key-value pairs, or "property name":"value" - but "a1U78000000SUtTEAW" is not (or doesn't look like) a property name.

Comment: @freedomn-m: Why not? Any string value can be a property name. The syntax of the object literal looks fine to me.

Comment: _"I have this JSON string"_ - theres no JSON in your question, only a javascript object

Comment: @FelixKling yes, the *syntax* is correct.  Are you saying you would create javascript objects such as:  `myvar.documents.a1U78000000SUtOEAW.Name`

Comment: @freedomn-m: Yes. `var obj = {documents: {a1U78000000SUtOEAW: {Name: "Hello"}}}; console.log(obj.documents.a1U78000000SUtOEAW.Name);`.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
  Object.keys(json.documents).forEach(key => {
      console.log("\n" + key + ": " + json.documents[key].Name);
  });
```

or this

```
  var documents= Object.values(json.documents);

  console.log(documents.length); //2
  console.log(documents[0].Id); // a1U78000000SUtTEAW
  console.log(documents[0].Name); // test2
```